# MySQL update and Sum in Query OR PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I have no idea How can it be done or is it possible In Query.?
Can be done in PHP.? If So any Idea or examples.

Here I have 2 tables.

**Review**

```
id    pid   published
--    ---   ---------
 1     12           0
 2     14           1
 3     16           1
```

**Rating**

```
id   rid   ratings                 sum
--   ---   ---------------------   -------
 1     2   4,5,3,3,3.5,5,5,5,4,5   42.5000
 2     4   4,5,3,3,3.5,5,5,5,4,5   42.5000
 3     1   5,5,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4     44.0000
```

What I would Like to Do is

1. Update the **Rating table** based on **Review.id = Rating.rid.**
2. Update ratings field where ever Is find **3** or **2** or **1** update to 4 like example this 4, 5, **3, 3, 3.5,** 5, 5, 5, 4, 5 should be 4, 5,  **4**, **4** ,**4**, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5
3. Based On update ratings field **SUM** field should Automatic Update the Sum of the rating values. Example this **42.5000** should be **45.0000**

I tried to explain my question if it is not clear please ask me to Modify or give you more detail.

My tables are exact same as example. ratings field has text data type. There Is no Another tables for ratings.

Any helps will be highly appreciate.

Thanks You.

Comment: Please tell me that the `ratings` column does not in fact have `4,5,3,3,3.5,5,5,5,4,5` as its data, and that you really have another table containing the one-to-many data

Comment: what is the data type of ratings column

Comment: Data Type of ratings is Text

Comment: LittleBobbyTables @ it Has That data IN fact this is the tricky Part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select Rating row (`SELECT * FROM Rating WHERE rid=YOUR_RID`)
- Fetch data in PHP (`mysqli_fetch()`, `PDOStatement->fetch()`, etc.)
- For transition string `ratings` to array use `explode` function
- For interaction with array you may use `foreach` cycle.

  $sum = 0;

  foreach ($array as &$rating) {

  if($rating < 4) $rating=4;

  $sum+=$rating;

  }

Comment: Marinin Tim @ it's working with sum but i have no idea how can I update 3 to 4 in ratings field and store in variable and insert.

Comment: Thanks for your help I'm near just left over is update ratings fields.

Comment: Thank You..Get It Work IN PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You should redesign your DB structure and store ratings' values in another table, for example, with structure like this

```
id | review_id | value
```

and then you would do all these things easily.

If this change is impossible, you probably should do it in PHP. I mean, you query all necessary data, explode `ratings` by `,` in array and do your operations over array.

But I highly recommend to move ratings in another table.

Comment: It is not possible to redesign DB structure.

Comment: In this case easiest way is to get all things done in PHP (including sum)

Comment: Marinin Tim @ Any example in PHP.?

Comment: @krishkim, I wrote example in another answer. If you need more detailed example, just ask.